# Multithreading summing give incorrect results

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm writing a little library and want to be able to sum an array.
A singlethread version works fine, but when I add multithreading, everything breaks.

I'm using a partitioner to split data on blocks and then sum every part in single result. Then I return it. But data is invalid, it's doesn't seems that there is any race condition, because every program reboot leads to same results.

```
[Pure]
public static double Sum(this double[] source)
{
    source.IsNotNull("source");
    if (source.Length < Constants.SingleThreadExecutionThreshold)
        return Sum(source, 0, source.Length);
    double result = 0;
    object syncRoot = new object();     
    Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, source.Length),
        () => (double)0,
        (range, state, sum) => Sum(source, range.Item1, range.Item2),
        x =>
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
                result += x;
        });

    return result;
}
```

`Sum(source, from, to)` always give correct results. Here is an implementation:

```
[Pure]
private static double Sum(this double[] source, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    double sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0, sum4 = 0;
    checked
    {
        int i;
        for (i = startIndex; i < endIndex - Constants.Step + 1; i += Constants.Step)
        {
            sum1 += source[i];
            sum2 += source[i + 1];
            sum3 += source[i + 2];
            sum4 += source[i + 3];
        }
        if (i == source.Length)
            return ((sum1 + sum2) + (sum3 + sum4));
        if (i == source.Length - 1)
            return ((sum1 + sum2) + (sum3 + sum4) + source[i]);
        if (i == source.Length - 2)
            return ((sum1 + sum2) + (sum3 + sum4) + (source[i] + source[i + 1]));
        return ((sum1 + sum2) + (sum3 + sum4) + (source[i] + source[i + 1] + source[i + 2]));
    }
}

internal static class Constants
{
    public const int Step = 4;
    public const int SingleThreadExecutionThreshold = 1024;
}
```

How can it be fixed?

---

Code example: http://ideone.com/8sD0JL

Comment: Did you try with `Interlocked.Add(ref result, x);` instead of using a `syncRoot` ?

Comment: I didn't, but it's definitly not a problem site, just a code style. Both ways gives the same result.

Comment: Please could you include your test case, possibly even put it into a fiddle.

Comment: @Aron of course, see edit

Comment: You must be doing some ***serious*** summing to go through all these optimizations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, think I've fixed it. I've found two major bugs.

1. the array.Length thing
2. you were misusing the "finally" delegate. There is no guarantee that that code ever gets run

With these changes I get a difference of -0.000576496124267578, which is within expected for double sum rounding errors.

```
    [Pure]
public static double Sum(this double[] source, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    double sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0, sum4 = 0;
    checked
    {
        int i;
        int j = 0;
        for (i = startIndex; i < endIndex - Constants.Step + 1; i += Constants.Step)
        {
            sum1 += source[i];
            sum2 += source[i + 1];
            sum3 += source[i + 2];
            sum4 += source[i + 3];
            j += Constants.Step;
        }
        var segmentLength = endIndex - startIndex;

        if (j == segmentLength)
            return ((sum1 + sum2) + (sum3 + sum4));
        if (j == segmentLength - 1)
            return ((sum1 + sum2) + (sum3 + sum4) + source[i]);
        if (j == segmentLength - 2)
            return ((sum1 + sum2) + (sum3 + sum4) + (source[i] + source[i + 1]));
        return ((sum1 + sum2) + (sum3 + sum4) + (source[i] + source[i + 1] + source[i + 2]));
    }
}

internal static class Constants
{
    public const int Step = 4;
    public const int SingleThreadExecutionThreshold = 1024;
}

[Pure]
public static double Sum(this double[] source)
{
    if (source.Length < Constants.SingleThreadExecutionThreshold)
        return Sum(source, 0, source.Length);
    double result = 0;
    object syncRoot = new object();     
    Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, source.Length),
        (range) => {

            var x = Sum(source, range.Item1, range.Item2);
            lock (syncRoot)
                result += x;
        });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: No, it's not a problem because endIndex is exclusive, when startindex is inclusive. And it doesn't explain why multithread code give 10 times less result than singlethread one. You can see `Sum(source, 0, source.Length)` doesn't throw IndexOutOfRangeException when last valid index is `source.Length - 1`

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy You also assume that each range is divisble by 4. I think the issue is you are doing source.Length (which is checking the divisablity of the whole array not your segment).

Comment: And that's true, I should compare with indices not with array.Length. Thanks, but it doesn't fix initial problem...

Comment: What is your initial problem, that you can rule this out? That `source.length` things is kind of major.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy Okay, think I've fixed it. I've found two major bugs. First, the array.Length thing. The second, you were misusing the "finally" delegate. There is no guarantee that that code ever gets run.

Comment: @Aron thanks. First problem is obvious, but I don't understand, how could `finally` delegate never gets run

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy Finally, is for clean up. I think its based on the GC finalize. I think the point is that you can return the result before the finally, which could take a long time.